# Decorating Ruby on Rails model with Draper inside callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror, draper, stimulus-reflex, cableready

I am using Cable Ready and draper gem in my rails project. I am having issues decorating inside a callback.
This is what I have in the `AppPayment`'s model callback:

```
  after_save do
    cable_ready[SplitsChannel].text_content(
      selector: "#payment-amount",
      text: payment.decorate.amount_f
    ).text_content(
      selector: "#left-to-pay",
      text: table_session.decorate.left_to_pay_f
    ).broadcast_to(split)
  end
```

When the callback is executed, I get in the server logs:

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications::InstrumentationSubscriberError (Exception(s) occurred within instrumentation subscribers: NoMethodError, NoMethodError):
```

This is the definition of `amount_f` in the `PaymentDecorator`:

```
  def amount_f
    h.to_brl(amount)
  end
```

`left_to_pay_f` is defined similarly.
This is the definition of `to_brl` in `ApplicationHelper`:

```
  def to_brl(centavos)
    number_to_currency(centavos.to_f / 100, unit: "R$", separator: ",", delimiter: ".")
  end
```

Running `payment.decorate.amount_f` and `table_session.decorate.left_to_pay_f` on an `AppPayment` instance works as expected in rails c. However, when the callback is executed, I get the error above.

Using the unformatted `payment.amount` and `table_session.left_to_pay` values in the cable ready operations also works, but sets the inner text of the targetted DOM elements to the unformatted values. Therefore the problem seems to come from decorating the associated records inside the callback.

Comment: Model shouldn't know somewhat about views, DOM, web sockets and decorators. Broadcast using callback is a bad idea. Call it from controller or some service object